# Regex in Redshift to access string between nested parentheses

Tags: python-3.x, regex, pandas

If I have a string "CompletenessConstraint(Completeness(contentname,None))"

How do I access only the part inside the nested parentheses?

For example in the above string, I want to access 'contentname'.

I tried the below

`str.extract(r"\((.*?)\)", expand=False)`

and get only "Completeness(contentname,None".

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The second value is always None?

Comment: Yes. CompletenessConstraint(Completeness(abc,None))
CompletenessConstraint(Completeness(abc,None))
CompletenessConstraint(Completeness(abc,None))
CompletenessConstraint(Completeness(abc,None)). I just want the string 'abc'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this pattern: `\b(?!.*\()\w+(?=,)`

See Regex [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/eUiWAn/2)

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to capture 1 or more word characters after the last opening parenthesis, and match the trailing comma followed by any char except `(` or a newline.

```
\((\w+),[^(\n\r]*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Isa0FC/1)